# Android studio Error - Failed to resolve : com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I have found an error during my android studio project. It shows:

> Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve:com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
>   Install Repository and sync project

and when i click on Install Repository and sync project it shows:

[image]

What should i do?

My XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hanumanbeniwal.www.hanumanbeniwal.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="586dp"
            android:layout_y="948dp" />
    </WebView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MY Java Coding -

```js
package com.hanumanbeniwal.www.hanumanbeniwal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.hanumanbeniwal.com/");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        
    }
}
```

My `build.gradle`**(Project)** Please check it...

```css
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hanumanbeniwal.www.hanumanbeniwal"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
}
```

My `builed.gradle`**(Module:app)** please check it...

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update Application level build.gradle to:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' from 2.x.x.`

This might help you.

Comment: Now it showing - Error:(1, 0)   Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. What should I do ?

Comment: Check your project level build.gradle file. See if anything's missing from `repositories` section.

Comment: I have checked and i have attached build.gradle file with my question so please check it and resolve my problem .

Comment: please help me . please resolve my problem.

Comment: "Update"? This is a downgrade

Comment: Thanks a lot guys... checkout my website - www.instantagiculture.com